# Как реализовать функцию "сохранить" в GUI?

Tags: java

Не могу никак разобраться с сохранением с текстового фрейма в текущий файл, У меня есть реализованная часть "сохранить как", как мне просто сохранить в текущий файл? Мне нужно по сути получить просто путь к открытому файлу

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
// Зберегти
}

private void saveasButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    int chooserValue = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (chooserValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try {   
            PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            fout.printf(textArea.getText());
            fout.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TextEditorFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В методе `saveasButtonActionPerformed` сохраняйте имя файла в поле класса (`this.currentFile = chooser.getSelectedFile()`). В `saveButtonActionPerformed` используйте его (`this.currentFile`).

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int chooserValue = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
if (chooserValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
           File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
           boolean isExist = true;
           if (!file.exists())
                isExist = file.mkdirs();

           if (isExist) 
              try (BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
                  byte[] content = textArea.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                  outputStream.write(content);
              }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```